# Link to SharePoint list that contains a counter

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, hyperlink, app-part

I am wondering if it is possible to create a hyperlink in SharePoint that contains a counter to the number of items in a list (more specifically the number of folders).

For example, if I had a document library named *Projects* that contains a folder for each individual project I am working on. Can I create a link to the library on another page that also contains a counter for the total number of folders (or files) that are present in the library.

For further clarification, let's say I have 25 folders in the *Projects* library that contain multiple files inside them. Can I make a link on a site page that looks like:

[Project Library (25)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176766/link-to-sharepoint-list-that-contains-a-counter)

Thank you very much!

Nick

Answer (score 0):

You might possibly consider adding a custom view to your list or library, and making use of the "Folder Child Count" field.  This will show the number of sub folders inside a folder.

[image]